# How to turn the number in a custom ordered-list in a clickable link?

Tags: html, css

At the moment when I click on "001" nothing happens and it's not considered as a link.

So what I would like to do is : being able to click on the "001" and being redirected to the link of the concerned list element ("Test" here).

```css
body {
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0;
}

    h1 {
  text-align: center;
 }

.custom-list {
  counter-reset: custom-counter;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.custom-list li:before {
  content: counter(custom-counter);
  counter-increment: custom-counter;
  content: "00" counter(custom-counter);
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<main>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <hr />
  <ol class="custom-list">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ol>
</main>
```

I would like to keep the custom list (00X) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: relative`

```css
body {
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-list {
  counter-reset: custom-counter;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.custom-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-list li:before {
  content: counter(custom-counter);
  counter-increment: custom-counter;
  content: "00" counter(custom-counter);
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-list li:hover:before, .custom-list li a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.custom-list li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <hr />
  <ol class="custom-list">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ol>
</main>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! What about a potential :hover state ? Let's say I wanted the whole link (number + "Test") to become red on :hover ? I managed to have something close to it but the border-bottom becomes red as well. If I try it on `.custom-list li a:hover` only "Test" become red.

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to use `:hover:before` for number and `a:hover` for a link